# Nested dictionary syntax ICE C++

Tags: c++, syntax, dictionary, ice

I have got a newbie problem with ZeroC ICE dictionary syntax. Here is what I tried and nothing seems to work.

```
/*What I want to make <flightNo, <hr, month day>>*/
dictionary<int, <short, short>> FlightSchedule;
dictionary<int, dictionary<short, short>> FlightSchedule;
```

How should I write it to be okay with the syntax?

Comment: Don't know what ICE is, but if you're not using C++11, you might need to add whitespace between closing angle brackets: `> >` in your second variant, which otherwise looks OK to me. Also, it's always nice to see exact error messages you get from your compiler in questions like this one.

Comment: ICE is a multilanguage framework - Internet Communications Engine. I`m trying to write client - server app. Unfortunately whitespace didn`t work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I found the solution.

```
dictionary<short, short> Time;
dictionary<int, Time> FlightSchedule
```

I`m wondering if there is any other solutions, because IMO syntax above is equal to:

```
dictionary<int, dictionary<short, short>> FS;
```